# Indexing issues when using cached exchange mode in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

My companies' IT department had set up my Outlook Client to also coincide with the web exchange. After they had done this, I was no longer able to index. I recently turned off my cached exchange mode, I never use my email on anything aside from my one work computer. After I turned it off, I have not had any indexing issues. Question for everyone else is, is this a known issue that others have also experienced and will I have other underlying issues in the future for doing as such

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off Cached Exchange Mode, the search will occur on the server side and give you the result after a little bit of "thinking".

In order to use Cached Exchange Mode, you also need to have Windows Search turned on. You can check Control Panel > Indexing Options and if you see Microsoft Outlook is listed there. If it is not there, then your Outlook search will not work.

[image]